# Symfony 4.4 An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: symfony

I come to you because I have looked for all the means but I cannot find a solution.

Here I have cloned a symfony 4.4 project

I launched it and everything went well except that here the debug bar does not appear and I have this error

An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.
I made **composer require symfony/apache-pack**

Composer tells me everything is up to date

Same for composer **require symfony/profiler-pack**

What I don't understand is until now when I cloned a project I still had the debug bar

And there I no longer have it.

How to display this bar?

Answer (score 0):

Check your [active environment.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#selecting-the-active-environment)
You should have `APP_ENV=dev` at `.env` or `.env.local` file.